# phonegap facebook connect with blackberry

Tags: blackberry, cordova

I'm trying to do a facebook connect with phonegap for Blackberry. I'm trying to do a simple login with facebook, authenticate, redirect to app. After that be able to like anything that I want.

I've done this with iPhone using Hackbook, but I haven't found any working solution for Blacbkerry. Any ideas?